# Repetir registro no banco de dados no mesmo dia de cada mês

Tags: php, datetime, data

Preciso fazer um agendamento de contas a pagar e que todo pagamento seria em um dia de cada mês.

Estou fazendo assim, porém não está dando certo:

```
$hoje = new DateTime($data_hoje);
                        $semana = new DateInterval('P'.$_POST['repetir'].'D');
                        $repeticoes = $_POST['repita'];

 for ($i_receber = 0 ; $i_receber < 30 - 1 ; $i_receber++) {

                            $hoje = $hoje->add($semana);

    Inserido com sucesso! Início2 <b><? echo $hoje->format('Y-m-d')

    }
```

Por exemplo se coloco para repetir todo dia 20 de cada mês, retorna assim

```
Inserido com sucesso! Início: 2019-05-20
Inserido com sucesso! Início: 2019-06-19
Inserido com sucesso! Início: 2019-07-19
```

**Quando deveria ser assim**

```
Inserido com sucesso! Início: 2019-05-20
Inserido com sucesso! Início: 2019-06-20
Inserido com sucesso! Início: 2019-07-20
```

Comment: Não vi a diferença do resultado da função com o resultado esperado. Você pode corrigir?

Comment: Insira na pergunta também como vem os dados do $_POST

Comment: @VictorCarnavalfoi corrigido

Comment: @AndréLins vem assim $semana = new DateInterval('P'.30.'D');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se quer somar 1 mês, não precisa fazer um loop somando dias, pode somar diretamente um `DateInterval` correspondente a um mês:

```
$d = new DateTime();
$d->setDate(2019, 5, 20); // 20 de maio de 2019
echo $d->format('d/m/Y'); // 20/05/2019
$d->add(new DateInterval('P1M')); // soma 1 mês => 20 de junho de 2019
echo $d->format('d/m/Y'); // 20/06/2019
```

`P1M` corresponde a uma duração de 1 mês, de acordo com o formato definido pela [norma ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations).

No seu código você usou `'P'.$_POST['repetir'].'D'`, cujo resultado será uma duração em dias (`P30D`, por exemplo, que corresponde a uma duração de 30 dias). Independente do valor utilizado, o resultado nem sempre será preciso, pois meses têm tamanhos variados: podem ter 28, 29, 30 ou 31 dias, e somar uma quantidade fixa de dias nem sempre resultará no mesmo dia do mês seguinte. Por isso é melhor usar uma duração em meses (como `P1M` para 1 mês).

Se quer repetir isso por vários meses, basta colocar em um loop:

```
$quantidade_meses = 3;
for ($i = 0 ; $i < $quantidade_meses ; $i++) {
    $d->add(new DateInterval('P1M'));
    echo $d->format('d/m/Y');
}
```

---

O único cuidado a se tomar é quando a data está nos últimos dias do mês. Ex:

```
$d = new DateTime();
// muda para 31 de janeiro de 2019
$d->setDate(2019, 1, 31);
// somar 1 mês = 3 de março de 2019
$d->add(new DateInterval("P1M"));
```

Ao somar 1 mês a 31 de janeiro de 2019, o resultado deveria ser 31 de fevereiro. Mas fevereiro não tem 31 dias, então o PHP ajusta para 3 de março.

Não sei até que ponto faz sentido somar 1 mês a uma data em janeiro e o resultado ser em março (dois meses depois). Nesses casos, muitas linguagens e APIs optam por ajustar o resultado para 28 de fevereiro, por exemplo. Se quiser o mesmo ajuste em PHP, [terá que fazê-lo manualmente](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5760262).

---

Outra alternativa é usar o método  [`modify`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php):

```
$d->modify('+1 month');
```

Mas ele tem o mesmo problema já citado para datas como 31 de janeiro de 2019 (resulta em 3 de março).