# Datas recorrentes a partir de uma inicial com PHP

Tags: php, php-7

Estou tentando trazer as próximas datas para inserir contas de um pagamento que se repete por X vezes, mas estou tendo problemas quando isso envolve os dias posteriores a 28 de fevereiro.

```
$qtde_meses = 6;
$cur_date = '2023-01-30';
$date = strtotime($cur_date);
$day = date("d", $date );

$newdate = new DateTime($cur_date);

    for ($i=0; $i<$qtde_meses; $i++) {
        $tmpDate = clone $newdate;
    
    if ($day == 31) {
        $tmpDate->modify('last day of +' . $i . ' month');
            
    } else {
        $tmpDate->modify('+' . $i . ' month');
    }
        $datafinal[] = $tmpDate->format('Y-m-d');   
    }
foreach($datafinal as $d) {
    echo $d;
}
```

O resultado do array acima, por exemplo, é:

```
2023-01-30
2023-03-02 <- Incorreto
2023-03-30
2023-04-30
2023-05-30
2023-06-30
```

Possuem alguma ideia para resolver isso? Testei em PHP 7.3 e 7.4.

Comment: Porque `2023-03-02` é a data incorreta e não `2023-03-30`?

Comment: Olá Augusto. Parece ser a data correta para o código acima, que somou 30 dias a partir da data inicial, mas para um boleto recorrente, deveria ser o último dia de fevereiro (28/02) ao invés de 02/03).

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/375462/112052

Comment: @hkotsubo já havia testado dessa forma e aqui ele piora a situação, pois ele soma 1 ao mês anterior do array e o resultado fica assim: 2023-01-30, 2022-03-02, 2023-04-02, etc..

Comment: $d = new DateTime();
$d->setDate(2022, 12, 30);
$quantidade_meses = 6;
for ($i = 0 ; $i < $quantidade_meses ; $i++) {
    $d->add(new DateInterval('P1M'));
    echo $d->format('d/m/Y');
}

Comment: Não é necessário essa lógica toda e nem clone (já que parece que não vai reusar) para operar a cada format, você poderia pegar, simplesmente usar o `last day` e então pegar os resultado com format adicionar ao array e só em seguida somar o +1 mês, isso no final da execução atual do loop

Comment: Oi @GuilhermeNascimento o código está um pouco sujo pela quantidade de tentativas que acabei fazendo, mas o problema não está sendo somar um mês e sim quando o resultado do array envolve o final de fevereiro, como explico no texto.. Preciso achar uma forma de fazer ele trazer o 28-fev e não o 02-mar..

Comment: É isso o que precisa https://ideone.com/O21zJm? (atualizado)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Valeu, mas não funciona.. Note que nesse caso vc usou o dia 30 e imprimindo o último dia de cada mês sequente.. Se eu lanço um boleto no dia 30, ele precisa se repetir no dia 30 de cada mês e não no dia 31, como acontece no seu resultado.. Isso corrige o caso de fevereiro, mas gera erro nos demais meses..

Comment: Não é só criar uma `if($x->format('d') > 30)` pra checar o dia, se passar do dia 30 você ajusta apenas o valor da variavel? Veja isso https://ideone.com/6Jj5Np

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não é necessário essa lógica toda com:

```
$date = strtotime($cur_date);
$day = date("d", $date );
```

E nem `clone`, já que parece que não vai reusar.

Para operar a cada `format`, você pode simplesmente usar o `last day of ... month`, em seguida pegar o dia obtido, checar se passou do 30 com uma `if ()`, se passou você só ajusta a variável do dia, e depois você pega só o ano e o mês e concatena com dia da variável que salvou anteriormente e em segui você usa o `modify('last day of +1 month')` para que no próximo uso seja o próximo mês.

Algo como:

```
<?php
 
$my_dates = [];
$qtde_meses = 6;

// Apenas ano e mês são suficientes no caso especifico
$cur_date = '2023-01';

// Dia limite que deseja
$dia_lancado = 30;
 
$date = new DateTime($cur_date);
 
// Define o último dia do mês atual
$date->modify('last day of this month');
 
for ($i = 0; $i < $qtde_meses; $i++) {
    // Pega o ultimo dia do mês atual
    $dia = $date->format('d');
 
    // Limita os dias ao 30 (conforme a variável)
    if ($dia > $dia_lancado) $dia = $dia_lancado;
 
    $my_dates[] = $date->format('Y-m') . '-' . $dia;
 
    // Vai para o último dia do próximo mês
    $date->modify('last day of +1 month');
}
 
print_r($my_dates);
```

Saída:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2023-01-30
    [1] => 2023-02-28
    [2] => 2023-03-30
    [3] => 2023-04-30
    [4] => 2023-05-30
    [5] => 2023-06-30
)
```

Teste online no ideone: https://ideone.com/6Jj5Np

Comment: Muito bom Guilherme. Funcionou pro que eu precisava!